# Split data frame by a set of specific dates

Tags: r, date

Hi I wanna split a data frame by a set of specific dates (not according to "month" or "week").

Here is the sample code

```
id <- c(1:6)
ts <- as.Date(c("2018-06-01","2018-06-25","2018-06-03","2018-05-06","2018-04-30","2018-06-13"))
df <- data.frame(id,ts)
split(df,cut(ts,breaks = c("2018-05-01","2018-05-20","2018-06-14")))
```

But it says invalid specification of breaks.

I am wondering how can I specify breaks in this case? I also tried cut.dates and tried different formats, e.g. "dd/mm/yy".

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
split(df, cut(
    df$ts, 
    breaks = as.Date(c("2018-04-30", "2018-05-01","2018-05-20","2018-06-14", "2018-06-30"))))
#$`2018-04-30`
#  id         ts
#5  5 2018-04-30
#
#$`2018-05-01`
#  id         ts
#4  4 2018-05-06
#
#$`2018-05-20`
#  id         ts
#1  1 2018-06-01
#3  3 2018-06-03
#6  6 2018-06-13
#
#$`2018-06-14`
#  id         ts
#2  2 2018-06-25
```

You need to specify `breaks` as `Date` objects when using `cut` with `Date`s. Notice also that I added a lower and upper break point because the `break` points you gave in your example did not cover the range of `Date`s in `df$ts`.